Attaching debugger to a running Node JS process inside a docker container
I normally use USR1 signal to run the node process in debug mode
kill -USR1 <pid>

but when the process is inside docker container - the node process by default listens on 127.0.0.1:9229 -> and thus I am not able to use container IP to connect to the now opened websocket.
The only way I got it working is by it listening on 0.0.0.0 node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 <process>; but this results in process starting in debug mode.
I want to attach debugger in runtime.
What is a good way to debug node process running in production in docker containers?
